# Rare crash NSExtension _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, crash

I have a rare crash I think it happens when a user tries to share a photo, again it is very rare, 1 crash out of 10,000 sessions.
Would be happy if anyone can give any info about what it can be?

Thanks!

```
Incident Identifier: 5ACBBA52-B09E-5668-E3EE-276C30303030
    CrashReporter Key:   None
    Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
    Process:         GOTit [10112]
    Path:            /var/containers/Bundle/Application/5BD13987-877E-4655-A1D0-2EE9F9A99EE2/GOTit.app/GOTit
    Identifier:      com.gotit.inc
    Version:         5.3.5 (5.3)
    Code Type:       ARM-64 (Native)
    Parent Process:  launchd [1]

    Date/Time:       2018-04-09 19:09:44.116 +0000
    OS Version:      iOS 11.2.6 (15D100)
    Report Version:  104

    Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGBUS)
    Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
    Crashed Thread:  6
    Thread 6 Crashed:
    0   Foundation                      0x0000000185cb4398 __85-[NSExtension _completeRequestReturningItems:forExtensionContextWithUUID:completion:]_block_invoke + 108
    1   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c42a54 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 24
    2   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c42a14 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
    3   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c4c96c _dispatch_queue_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 528
    4   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c4d2fc _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 340
    5   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c4dd20 _dispatch_root_queue_drain_deferred_wlh$VARIANT$mp + 404
    6   libdispatch.dylib               0x0000000184c5603c _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread$VARIANT$mp + 644
    7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184eeaf1c _pthread_wqthread + 932
    8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000184eeab6c start_wqthread + 4
```